# How to apply a function to a specific element in tuples in a list

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, enumeration

I've got a list of tuples of type `([Char], Int, Int)`, and I want to modify the value of the first integer of each tuple, `(_, x, _)`, so that this value enumerates the items starting from 1:

```hs
function [("hi", 4, 2), ("hi", 27, 3) , ("moon", 9, 2)]
> result: [("hi", 1, 2), ("hi", 2, 3), ("moon", 3, 2)]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I think downvotes to this question are very mean. Here we have someone who asked a very specific question, without cluttering it with useless details and pages of useless comments. There was some language difficulty, but the question overall is good.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example (the text really was confusing - I hope I could fix it a bit) you can use a list-comprehension + `zip`:

```hs
enumItems :: [(String, Int, Int)] -> [(String, Int, Int)]
enumItems items = [ (str, i, n) |  ((str,_,n), i) <- zip items [1..] ]
```

your example:

```hs
Prelude> enumItems [("hi", 4, 2), ("hi", 27,3) , ("moon", 9, 2)]
[("hi",1,2),("hi",2,3),("moon",3,2)]
```

---

there is also `zipWith` if you prefer this:

```hs
enumItems :: [(String, Int, Int)] -> [(String, Int, Int)]
enumItems items = zipWith (\(str, _, n) i -> (str, i, n)) items [1..]
```

and if you flip the order of `items` and `[1..]` you can have a nice point-free (meaning: no need for the **point** `items`) version:

```hs
enumItems :: [(String, Int, Int)] -> [(String, Int, Int)]
enumItems = zipWith (\i (str, _, n) -> (str, i, n)) [1..]
```

that's probably the version I'd use.

---

both variants uses a neat little trick: as Haskell is lazy you can *zip* the infinite list `[1..] = [1,2,3,4,...]` on any list `[i1,i2,i3,...]` and get pairs `[(i1,1),(i2,2),...]` the length of the other list does not matter.

AFAIK there are nor variants like `mapi` etc. you sometimes see in other languages to `map` with an index - it's always that trick (at least I use this trick constantly in these situations)

Answer (score 1):

There is [`indexed` in `Data.List.Index`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ilist-0.4.0.1/docs/Data-List-Index.html#v:indexed) which allows you to attach an index to every element of a list. So in your case you would get a `[(Int, ([Char], b, c))]`, and you would just write a function to reorganize the tuples, like this:

```hs
import Data.List.Index (indexed)

rearrange (i,(s,_,j)) = (s,i,j)
function = map rearrange . indexed

input = [("hi", 4, 2), ("hi", 27, 3) , ("moon", 9, 2)]
result = function input
```

This way you get the elements indexed from 0. If you want them from one, you just have to change the one bit:

```
rearrange (i,(s,_,j)) = (s,i+1,j)
```